# Displaying Date (c# winforms)

Tags: c#

I have a SQL Table with the following columns:

```
PROFILE
----------------------------------
Name | DateOfBirth | Address | ID
----------------------------------
     |             |         |
     |             |         |
```

`[Name]` is a required field while the `ID` is an `autoincrement` column.
The remaining fields are not required.

When it comes to displaying again the information of a user in my form, since the DateOfBirth field is not required I always got this value in my textBox `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000` even if it not supplied upon registration.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to display an empty string inthe textBox if the there's no date of birth.

With my naive way of thinking, I wrote a method where it checks first the DateOfBirth column, if it is null, it will return an empty string, else, return the date of birth as a string ex. `txtDateOfBirth.Text = GetDateOfBirth();`
but it always return the value `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' cause the field in the database always inserts this value even the user leaves this field as blank.

Can you please help me... thanks...

I also tried this but still don't work:

```
SELECT BIRTHDATE = CASE BIRTHDATE
            WHEN CAST('1900-01-01' AS DATETIME) THEN '' 
            ELSE BIRTHDATE END
FROM USER
```

Comment: Please post the code behind `GetDateOfBirth()`, or its equivalent.

Comment: Also, what do you see in the table when you query it directly (with, assuming SQL Server, SQL Server Workbench)?  `SELECT BIRTHDATE FROM USER`.

Comment: Assuming the user did not supplied his date of birth:

Comment: i run a simple select statement: select * from user

Comment: this is the result: USER1 | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
| Address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it already! :)

Here's my original code:

```
protected void SaveUser()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT_USER");
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NAME", txtName.Text.Trim()));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ADDRESS", txtAddress.Text.Trim()));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DATEOFBIRTH", txtDateOfBirth.Text.Trim()));
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

In my original code, even though `txtDateofBirth` is empty, it will always pass an empty string to the parameter causing the database to insert '1900-01-01 00:00:00.00', not the `NULL` value. Here's the modified code. I check first if `txtDateOfBirth` is not empty (assuming the value entered is a valid date) if true, add `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DATEOFBIRTH", txtDateOfBirth.Text.Trim()));` as a parameter to `INSERT_USER` stored procedure. Else, `@DATEOFBIRTH` parameter is not being created and passed at all.

```
protected void SaveUser()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT_USER");
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NAME", txtName.Text.Trim()));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ADDRESS", txtAddress.Text.Trim()));
    if(txtDateOfBirth.Text.Trim() != String.Empty)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DATEOFBIRTH", txtDateOfBirth.Text.Trim()));
        }
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[INSERT_USER] 
(
    @NAME AS VARCHAR(25),
    @ADDRESS AS VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @DATEOFBIRTH AS DATETIME = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [USER] ([NAME], ADDRESS, DATEOFBIRTH) VALUES (@NAME, @ADDRESS, @DATEOFBIRTH)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

My psychic debugging skills tell me that you're mistakenly setting the birthdate when you insert the row. A good check for that is to hook up a profiler (one comes with SQL Server, if that's what you're using), and watch what's actually getting inserted when you create a new user.

Check the code that's inserting a new user. If you're using DataSets, for instance, check that you don't have a default constraint set on the Birthdate column (click on the cell in the DataSet designer, and check the Properties grid).

It's also possible that the database itself has a default constraint set on that column, but that feels less likely.

Comment: private string ReturnDateOfBirth()
{
 string  dateOfBirth = String.Empty;
   pl.ConnOpen();
            pl.cmd = new SqlCommand("GET_DATEOFBIRTH", pl.MySQLConn);
            pl.cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", (object)txtID.Text.Trim()));
            pl.cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            pl.dr = pl.cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if(pl.dr.HasRows)
   {
    dateOfBirth = pl.dr["DateOfBirth"].ToString();
   }
            pl.MySQLConn.Close();
            return dateOfBirth;
}

Comment: @yonan2236: I'm actually suggesting that the problem's in the insert, not the select.

Comment: I also set the DateOfBirth Column as Nullable and has no default constraint. but it seems it always inserts '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'

Comment: @yonan2236: ok, so what does the code look like that's inserting that date?

Comment: CREATE   PROC [dbo].INSERT_USER
( @NAME VARCHAR(25), @DATEOFBIRTH AS DATETIME = NULL, @ADDRESS AS VARCHAR(100) = null) AS BEGIN INSERT INTO USER (NAME, DATEOFBIRTH, ADDRESS) VALUES (@NAME, @DATEOFBIRTH, @ADDRESS) END GO

Comment: @yonan2236, I still want to see the **code**. Not the stored procedure, but the **code calling that stored procedure**.

Comment: +1 for Michael - just for taking the effort to do psychic debugging!! It aint easy!!

Comment: cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT_USER");
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NAME", (object)txtName.Text.Trim()));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DATEOFBIRTH", GetDateOfBirth()));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ADDRESS", txtAddress.Text.Trim()));

                cmd.Connection = pl.ConnOpen();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: @yonan2236: Ok... we could go on like this for a while, but try this: obviously, the birthdate is coming as a return value from `GetDateOfBirth()`. Put a breakpoint on all lines in `GetDateOfBirth()` that return a value. See what the return values are at those points, when you try to create a new user.

Comment: If you find that the date is incorrect (1900...) at that point, continue to walk backwards until you find where that date is being created.

Comment: this is the trace result in the profiler when i do not supply dateofbirth:

Comment: exec INSERT_USER @NAME = N'PETER PAN', @ADDRESS = N'SESSAME STREET'

Comment: Hmm. Ok, then dump the DDL for your table.

Comment: Ahmm..sorry sir, but what do you mean dump?

Comment: I want to look at the definition for that table. I don't have SQL Workbench in front of me, but you want to do something like right-click on the table in the object explorer, select `Tasks->Script Table to New Window`

Comment: It might be too long to post. Look for anything related to that column. Also look for whatever triggers you might have defined on that table.

Comment: if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[User]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
drop table [User]
GO

CREATE TABLE [User] (
 [User] [varchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,
 [DateOfBirth] [datetime] NULL ,
 [Address] [varchar] (100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
 [ID] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Comment: I have no triggers sir, or any relationships to other tables

Comment: Hmm. Well, we've proven that you're inserting rows correctly, but the database is storing them with the incorrect dates. That should narrow your work down. Check for any default constraints on that table, and any triggers. You could also look for anything else (other sprocs, triggers, jobs) that are touching that table.

Comment: anyway sir, thank you so much for your time and effort trying to solve this problem... I just can't figure out why this unexpected behavior happens.

Comment: It sounds like you've got a database problem, and not a code problem. You might repose your question as that. Describe the steps you've taken here to show that you're inserting the data correctly, but SQL Server (it **is** SQL Server, right? It occurs to me that you've never verified that) isn't reporting it correctly.

Comment: yes sir, I'm using Microsoft SQL Enterprise Manager

Microsoft Corporation

Version: 8.0

Comment: i tried mr. Conrad Frix's post. It works, but I'm not contented. Cause that's what I always do, comparing a constant value and that code is something just not flexible,,... is it ok to use sir?

Comment: @yonan: You're right to not be content. It's a [workaround](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workaround). It'll hide the problem, but the problem is still there, lurking.

Comment: @yonan: re: voting: That's up to you. If it solved your problem, why not.

Comment: I gave to you sir the credit. Anyway, It's just a point. I know mr. Conrad Frix won't mind.

Comment: I got it sir! Please see my answer... :)

Comment: Should i give my self the credit? hehehe... thanks again sir.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you don't want to do this?

```
string theDate = GetDateOfBirth().ToString();
txtDateOfBirth.Text = theDate  == "1900-01-01 00:00:00.000" ? "" : theDate;
```

Comment: hmm...ok i wil try.. but what does the second line means?

Comment: if the date is "1900-01-01 00:00:00.00" then set the text box text to display an empty string otherwise display the theDate. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4213hs1(VS.71).aspx